# If content in a cell is too long, show "Multiple" instead of letting the text overflow in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

So, I have a custom function that concatenate different cells and put a comma between words.

For example, say I have "ABCD" "BC" then, this function will
output ABCD, BC. Now the problem is that the text will overflow in a cell and overlap with the cell next to that. In order to solve this problem,

I am thinking of just replacing the concatenated word with "Multiple" if more than 3 words are combined. Is there anyway to do this in a cell?

Comment: Why not show your current code so we can make suggestions?

Comment: Or you could just format the cells to wrap the text

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with conditional formatting AND keep the original underlying string as a raw value for other purposes.

1. Select the cells with the formula and create a conditional formatting rule based on a formula.
    
           `=LEN(C2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C2, ",", ""))>1`
2. Click Format and go to the **Numbers** tab. Choose **Custom** from the list down the left side and supply the following for the **Type:**
    
           `;;;[color13]_((\multipl\e)`
    
     I've opted to also make the font dark blue (colorindex # 13) and indent from the left.

Click <kbd>OK</kbd> to accept the formatting and then <kbd>OK</kbd> again to create the new rule.

[image: multiple_strings]

As you can see in the sample image above, the underlying raw value remains (shown in the formula bar) but [(multiple)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-format-codes-5026BBD6-04BC-48CD-BF33-80F18B4EAE68) is displayed.

---

<sub>More on custom number formatting codes at [Number format codes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-format-codes-5026BBD6-04BC-48CD-BF33-80F18B4EAE68)</sub>